# Serve two react apps with Nginx on same domain (403 error)

Tags: reactjs, nginx

I am trying to configure Nginx (over debian 10) to serve two fronts (npm run build) of react.

All works fine on the first app "/", but not on "/administracion/"
This is the configuration that I am using, and when I access I receive a 403. It does not seem like a permission problem, because it does not matter what I load, I always receive 403.

```
  server {
        listen 80;
        server_name x.net;
        root /var/www/html/front_web/build;

        index index.html;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }

        location /administracion/ {
                alias /var/www/html/front_admin/build;
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }
  }
```

The App is created with react-router (I think this does not affect anything).

Answer (score 3):

Are you using any routing libraries? If this is a CRA app, try setting the [homepage property](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment#serving-the-same-build-from-different-paths). Otherwise all your JS and assets will try to be served from root.

Comment: Yes! I had configured the package.json but not the BrowseRouter.
Now it works, but only in the baseurl of the second app, when it tries to load a path beyond (/ base / x) it returns to the main App with no content.
Should I configure some routes in the routing of the main App?

Comment: @AlfredoHinarejos I had the very same problem yesterday where `/some/path` was not working while `/some/path/` with the trailing slash *did* work when accessed in the browser. Haven't figured it out completely yet.